# $.getJSON used by desktop widget does not request URL from browser

Tags: javascript, php, getjson

I am developing a Desktop widget (in Windows 7). I have created an API (using PHP) which the widget needs to request data from. The API is in JSON format, and by typing the URL in the browser I get the data I need, which is

```
{"a": "b"}
```

I also checked the JSON API in http://jsonlint.com which shows that the JSON is correct.

The javascript code I use to get the JSON from the URL is the following :

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
     ... printings ...
});
```

but I don't get any results (whereas the URL shows the correct results when typing it). When I open the Network Tab, I can see that the URL is not even requested! The server request does not return anything, it's like I didn't request the URL.

However, when I type a different URL (not created by me, but from my company, using Python), the widget gets the data. I suppose that there is therefore something wrong with my API, but I cannot figure out what. In the PHP code creating the API I have

```
<?php
  ....
  $str = 'b';
  ....
  $results = array();
  $results['a'] = $str;
  $encoded = json_encode($results);
  echo $encoded;
  return $encoded;
?>
```

and I get the JSON I show above.  Any ideas?

Comment: how is `output` related to `function(data)` which is a callback?

Comment: @Sumit I'm sorry, I have another external function which has "output" as an argument. It is not used here in the way I have written the question,  I am editing the code, thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by *DesktopWidget*?

Comment: @low_rents it is a gadget for Windows, you could have a look at http://win7gadgets.com/ to understand what I mean. I am developing a gadget such as those.

Comment: @Marievi and you are sure your gadget (however you are coding it) will support `jQuery`. plus you will need cross-domain-support, so you need to use a `JSONP` request.

Comment: @low_rents it does not have any problem supporting javascript/jQuery. Could you explain the second part of your comment?

Comment: @Marievi your browser is the widget or gadget itself - kindof. and you are sending a request to a webserver somewhere else (i guess). so you neet to use JSONP in order to make it cross-domain compatible. otherwise your normal JSON request will be blocked, because normal `ajax` requests only work when staying in the same domain.

Comment: @low_rents Thanks a lot. I understood what you said but could you help me get started to use it in my code? How can I use JSONP? Should I change the way I request the URL?

Comment: _If the URL includes the string `"callback=?"` (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead._ - taken from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/.

Comment: @low_rents the link I request is something like 

                               "link.php?callback=?" . 

When I type it in the browser, I get the same JSON as when I type "link.php". Should the JSON returned follow a "?" character, i.e. 

                                         ?{"a":"b"}
?

Comment: @Marievi no, as far as i know the JSON returned should not change at all. JSONP just allows the browser (or widget in your case) to do a cross-domain request - otherwise a cross-domain-request would get blocked (within a widget silently, I assume)

Comment: @low_rents right now though this is the situation in my code.. However thanks!

Comment: @Marievi what is the situation in your code? what do you mean?

Comment: @low_rents I mean that right now, I request a URL 

"link.php?callback=?" , and the JSON is the same whether I type "link.php" or "link.php?callback=?" . So I cannot understand why the problem exists.

Comment: @Marievi but that's in your browser, i guess. and you'll most probably have a test-script on the same webserver in the same domain which you are opening in your browser? but if you are testing it with the widget, then you have a local script that is trying to send a request to a server. and that's why you will need JSONP, imho.

Comment: @low_rents Ok Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

there must be obviously something wrong with the javascript part. and i don't know what you mean by *Desktop Widget*.
your javascript isn't outputting anything from your JSON response. let's change that by printing `data.a`, which should be the variable of your response:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
       output+= "<p> my JSON response: " + data.a + " </p>";
       document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = output;
       //whenDone (output);
});
```

to be honest, i don't what you are trying to achieve with `whenDone(output)`. is this a function written by yourself?
you realize that `$.getJSON()` is a jQuery function - so make sure you included jQuery in your code. and also make sure that your script is in `<script></script>` tags.

Comment: I have edited my code. I use the "output" because I have an external function calling $.getJSON but I don't display it here to make things simpler. Therefore, it is not used in the way I have written the code. Could you erase your comment so as to keep it clear? Sorry and thanks.

Comment: @Marievi no, this is not a comment. this is an answer. and you should give us more of your original code so we are able to help you - and not remove more from your original code. are you not getting any errors in your console, btw? and make sure you have "preserve log" (or similar) checked in your console, so you don't lose log entries when refreshing.

Comment: The reason I asked you to erase your answer is that I edited my code because I wrote the "output" variable by mistake, it is not used here. I believe the problem is in my PHP code used to create the JSON API. I cannot use console.log() because the results of my code cannot be tested in the browser (as in a webpage) but directly in the gadget, which does not have a console. If you mean the console through the Network tab, it does not show anything.